# What switch statement produces the least efficient machine code?

Tags: performance, switch-statement, machine-code

I've got a question in one of my tests that asked me to answer what switch statement produce the least efficient machine code. The possible answers were O4, O1, O2, or O3. I don't event know what those are supposed to mean.

Comment: Depends on compiler and language? Need context

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misread that question (probably not about switch statements, but compiler switches), and your question here is utterly unanswerable as-is - context, code, language all missing.

Comment: @Deco There was no context. That's the whole question.

Comment: "That's the whole question." Verbatim? Did it really say switch *statement*? Not compiler switch? Or compilation option?

Comment: @Paul Manta: O1, O2, ... are compiler switches, not C-style switch statements.

Comment: @Thilo Actually it says just "switch", not "switch statement". The word "compiler" doesn't appear.

Comment: I'm not in your class, so I don't know the answer either...

Comment: You've got to *run* from the place where they're asking this sort of "questions". Run as fast as you can.

Comment: Memorizing compiler switches seems like a complete waste of time. That's what documentation is for. The real trick is understanding what the docs mean.

Comment: -O4 was the answer to the question on your test by the way...

Comment: @dwelch: Wrong. «-O4» means optimize for speed and size + perform LTO. It generates perfectly efficient switch code. Even if no optimization is selected, GCC would generate a jump table. Though this is compiler specific and the whole question may not make any sense.

Comment: the optimization for gcc is modulo 3 so -O4 is a -O0  -O5 is a -O1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC [Options That Control Optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

> -O
>   -O1
>      Optimize. Optimizing compilation takes somewhat more time, and a lot more memory for a large function.
>
> -O2
>      Optimize even more. GCC performs nearly all supported optimizations that do not involve a space-speed tradeoff. As compared to -O, this option increases both compilation time and the performance of the generated code.
>
> -O3
>       Optimize yet more
>
> -Os
>       Optimize for size.
>
> -Ofast
>       Disregard strict standards compliance. -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations. It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard compliant programs

Comment: I think the option numbers in gcc are modulo three so -O4 is really -O0.  Pretty easy to test...